# Python passing onclick variables with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to pass variables from one function to another in Python, but for some reason it returns nothing. Please see the code below. The current error is that 'Register' does not have any attributes of 'entryNumber'

```
 import tkinter as tk

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)
HEIGHT = 700
WIDTH = 800

class programStart(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self) #Frame in window
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=WIDTH)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=HEIGHT)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, Register, LoginPage):
            frame = F(container, self, bg='#80c1ff')
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise() #Raises to front


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller, bg=None, fg=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg=bg, fg=fg)

   
        #MAIL

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Mail:", bg="#80c1ff")
        label.place(relx=0.30, rely=0.05, relwidth=0.05, relheigh=0.05)

        entryMail = tk.Entry(self, bg="white")
        entryMail.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.05, relwidth = 0.2, relheigh=0.05)

        #PASSWORD

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Last Name:", bg="#80c1ff")
        label.place(relx=0.28, rely=0.15, relwidth=0.1, relheigh=0.05)

        entryPw = tk.Entry(self, bg="white")
        entryPw.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.15, relwidth = 0.2, relheigh=0.05)

        buttonS_2 = tk.Button(self, text="Login",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(LoginPage))
        buttonS_2.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.25, relwidth = 0.2, relheigh=0.05)

        buttonS_2 = tk.Button(self, text="Register",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Register))
        buttonS_2.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.35, relwidth = 0.2, relheigh=0.05)

   

class Register(tk.Frame):
    def appendUser(self):
        print(self.entryNumber.get())

    def __init__(self, parent, controller, bg=None, fg=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg=bg, fg=fg)

        ###################################### DESIGN ################################

        #NAME

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Name:", bg='#80c1ff')
        label.place(relx=0.30, rely=0.05, relwidth=0.05, relheigh=0.05)

        entryName = tk.Entry(self, bg="white")
        entryName.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.05, relwidth = 0.2, relheigh=0.05)


        #LAST NAME

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Last Name:", bg='#80c1ff')
        label.place(relx=0.28, rely=0.15, relwidth=0.1, relheigh=0.05)

        entryLastname = tk.Entry(self, bg="white")
        entryLastname.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.15, relwidth = 0.2, relheigh=0.05)

        #AGE

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Age:", bg='#80c1ff')
        label.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.25, relwidth=0.1, relheigh=0.05)

        entryAge = tk.Entry(self, bg="white")
        entryAge.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.25, relwidth = 0.2, relheigh=0.05)

        #E-MAIL

        label = tk.Label(self, text="E-Mail:", bg='#80c1ff')
        label.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.35, relwidth=0.1, relheigh=0.05)

        entryMail = tk.Entry(self, bg="white")
        entryMail.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.35, relwidth = 0.2, relheigh=0.05)

        labelM = tk.Label(self, text="", bg='#80c1ff', fg='red')
        labelM.place(relx=0.62, rely=0.35, relwidth=0.35, relheigh=0.05)

        #Phone number

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Phone:", bg='#80c1ff')
        label.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.45, relwidth=0.1, relheigh=0.05)

        entryNumber = tk.Entry(self, bg="white")
        entryNumber.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.45, relwidth = 0.2, relheigh=0.05)

        labelN = tk.Label(self, text="", bg='#80c1ff', fg='red')
        labelN.place(relx=0.62, rely=0.45, relwidth=0.35, relheigh=0.05)

        #SUBMIT BUTTON

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Submit", fg='blue', command=self.appendUser)
        button.place(relx=0.43, rely=0.55, relwidth=0.1, relheigh=0.05)


        ################################################################################
        buttonR_1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back To Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        buttonR_1.place(relx=0.43, rely=0.75, relwidth=0.1, relheigh=0.05)
        
        ###################################### END DESIGN ################################




class LoginPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller, bg=None, fg=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg=bg, fg=fg)

        ###################################### DESIGN ################################

        label = tk.Label(self, text = "You Are Logged In", font=LARGE_FONT, bg="#80c1ff")
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        buttonR_1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back To Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        buttonR_1.pack()
        
        ###################################### END DESIGN ################################

app = programStart()
app.mainloop()
```

It did not work with global variable as well as trying to pass the variable through 'command' on the button. I have also tried with self.entryNumber.get() even though this still does not result in any results.

I highly appreciate every suggestion that might come in and thank you in advance.

Comment: Nothing in your code says "onclick", nor do you have any bindings for button clicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `.place` doesn't expand the frame. That is why I use `.pack` and `.grid`. If you pass in the `width` and `height` parameters when creating the frame the widgets should show on the screen.

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class Register(tk.Frame):
   def appendUser(self):
       print(entryNumber.get())

   def __init__(self, parent, controller, bg=None, fg=None):
       global entryNumber
       tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg=bg, fg=fg, width=500, height=500)

       entryNumber = tk.Entry(self, bg="white")
       entryNumber.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.45, relwidth=0.2, relheigh=0.05)

       button = tk.Button(self, text="Submit", fg='blue', command=self.appendUser)
       button.place(relx=0.43, rely=0.55, relwidth=0.1, relheigh=0.05)


root = tk.Tk()
reg = Register(root, "controller")
reg.pack()
```

Please note that I don't have all of the code so the problem might actually be with whatever creates the `Register` class object.

It's better to assign `entryNumber` to `self` like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class Register(tk.Frame):
   def appendUser(self):
       print(self.entryNumber.get())

   def __init__(self, parent, controller, bg=None, fg=None):
       tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg=bg, fg=fg, width=500, height=500)

       self.entryNumber = tk.Entry(self, bg="white")
       self.entryNumber.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.45, relwidth=0.2, relheigh=0.05)

       button = tk.Button(self, text="Submit", fg='blue', command=self.appendUser)
       button.place(relx=0.43, rely=0.55, relwidth=0.1, relheigh=0.05)


root = tk.Tk()
reg = Register(root, "controller")
reg.pack()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's showing, but the variable from entryNumber is not being passed into appendUser function. The frame and all that seems to work just fine.

Comment: @DenisZakamulin it's a global variable so you don't need to pass it in. I will edit it with some better code

Comment: Thanks, it now shows: AttributeError: 'Register' object has no attribute 'entryNumber'. Do you know what might cause this @TheLizzard?

Comment: @D_Mulin Do you have the `self.entryNumber = tk.Entry(self, bg="white")`?